# Python - About the results retrieved from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, string

```
>>> c = conn.cursor()

>>> c.execute('select * from stocks order by price')
>>> for row in c:
...    print row
...

(u'2006-01-05', u'BUY', u'RHAT', 100, 35.14)

(u'2006-03-28', u'BUY', u'IBM', 1000, 45.0)
```

As what we can see, there's an 'u' in front of each column. And it's getting worse in my db.

How could we print the normal string?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the feeling that you are not very accustomed to using Unicode. To begin with ([1](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)):

> "**There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text.**
>
> If you have a string, in memory, in a
>   file, or in an email message, you have
>   to know what encoding it is in or you
>   cannot interpret it or display it to
>   users correctly."

u in front of a text marks that you are dealing with a `unicode` object instead of `string` object. Thus, if you make a string representation of a unicode object, the u will always appear.

In order to remove the u, you need to encode the `unicode` object with some specific encoding. For instance, if you are using a console that has utf-8 encoding, you wish to create an `utf-8` encoded string representation of your data.

Unicode objects can be encoded with `encode`. For instance:

```
print row[0].encode('utf-8')
```

Should result in

```
2006-01-05
```

...IF your console/terminal is using the same encoding (utf-8).

Similarly you can iterate through the tuples:

```
for row in c:
    print tuple(x.encode('utf-8') for x in row)
```

I absolutely, positively recommend, possibly even insist you to read "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)". Unicode may be tough to begin with, but when you master the concepts, it will be your new best friend - and the more `u`'s you will see, the happier you will get. Trust me.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is too old, but I had the same issue using Python3. I added `use_unicode=False` to my connection block:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="username",
    password="password",
    database="databasename",
    use_unicode=False
)
   
cursor = mydb.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM Server")
for name in cursor:
   print(name)
```

Results:

```
('Server1',)
```

I found the answer [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html), `Character Encoding` paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

'u' represents unicode. You can work with them just like strings. If you really want strings then do `str(u'BUY')`.

**UPDATE: I misred the question. The below code is for MySQL DB not mysqli. Sorry for the confusion. Not removing the content.**

Also, just a suggestion. Instead of of just using a cursor which returns a tuple as result set. Use 'dict' as cursor. It'll give you an easy to access dictionary with field names as keys & its corresponding values as rows. This is more pythonic. This could be done like so -

```
cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

instead of

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Where conn is your connection object got from `MySQLdb.connect()` method

Comment: hey! just do str(<your_value>). Also there is no ",". str(u, cols) is definitely a syntax error.

Comment: str(u'mystring'), the u goes before a string *literal*.

Comment: I used  conn = connect('db')
        cur = conn.cursor() to get my conn

Comment: do this tuple(str(val) for val in cols).

Comment: Tried tuple(str(val) for val in cols). Nothing has changed...Help~~~~

Comment: I'm sorry to give you a negative vote, but I actually consider your answer to be harmful. str(u'BUY') is not universally safe. Invoking str() with unicode input will result in using default encoder (ascii). Even a single unicode character outside this charset will result in UnicodeEncodeError.

Comment: hey that's what the good man wants! I am not going to argue with that!! :) Also others have suggested the same solution. That's how one converts a unicode string to string. I know the 'correct' method is to decode the string using <str_value>.decode('utf8').

Comment: @jsalonen I read. I am not even sure what the 'user' wants normal strings. unicode encoded strings are good to carry on with.

Comment: Yeah well good point -- after re-reading the question I'm not sure about that either :/ Some more information from the question asker is totally needed for a best possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the unicode strings in the row tuple into regular strings:

```
for row in c:
    print tuple(str(x) for x in row)
```

Comment: NO, the 'u' still in front of each field./``